# Declare a dependency on only secure versions of a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependency-management

My gem depends on ActiveSupport and has been tested successfully with ActiveSupport 3.2, 4.1 and 4.2.

Some versions of ActiveSupport have the vulnerability [CVE-2015-3227](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2015-3227) and I want to exclude those versions from my dependency declaration.

The dependency is currently declared like this:

`spec.add_runtime_dependency 'activesupport', '>= 3.2.22', '< 5'`

but this includes insecure versions of ActiveSupport 4.1 and 4.2.

Is there a way of excluding those insecure versions from the dependency?